# View vim variables with names matching pattern (i.e. show variables with name containing "airline")

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I can see a plugin's configurable variables by running

```
:let
```

But, as more are installed, this gets tedious.  And they aren't alphabetically sorted.

I can of course go through the plugin's documentation.

In vim, is there a way to see all variables with names matching a pattern?  Like, what if I want to see all variables containing `airline`?  Not just ones starting with `airline`, but also ones with prefixes like `b:airline_whitespace_check`?

Regardless of if there's way built into vim to do this, is there a way to pipe the contents of `:let` through `grep` through a subshell?  So something like this could be done:

```
<magic that echos :let to subshell> | grep airline | sort
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use command-line completion:

```
:let qf<C-d>
qf_mapping_ack_style            qf_mapping_filegroup_next
qf_mapping_filegroup_previous   qf_statusline
```

Note that `:let` won't show you *all* plugin variables. It only shows those that are defined in the current context.

---

The "new" `:help :filter` command sadly doesn't work on `:let` so it's useless here.

---

Another way:

```
:redir @a
:let
:redir END
:vnew
@ap
:v/qf/d
```

Comment: `:filter` works on `:let` if Vim includes the patch [8.1.0495](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0495).